Fluid dynamics in Newtonian regime from action
I struggle to understand how one can get the Euler, continuity and Poisson equation describing a fluid in the weak gravity regime from the Einstein-Hilbert plus fluid matter action. Say I start from
$$
S=\frac{1}{2\kappa} \int d^4x\sqrt{-g}R~+~\int d^4x\sqrt{-g}mn(x)(g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu\chi\partial_\nu\chi+1)~,
$$
where $m$ is the mass of the particles in the fluid and $n(x)$ is both the Lagrange multiplier enforcing $\partial_\mu\chi\partial^\mu\chi=u_\mu u^\mu=-1$ and the fluid's number density. Now, I consider the weak-field regime of Newtonian gravity on a flat background
$$
ds^2=-(1-2\Phi)dt^2+(1+2\Phi)\delta_{ij}dx_i dx_j
$$
which, at second order in the (static) potential $\Phi$, gives $\sqrt{-g}\simeq 1-2\Phi-2\Phi^2$ and
$$
S_{EH}\simeq\frac{1}{\kappa}\int d^4x[\nabla^2\Phi-(\nabla\Phi)^2)]~.
$$
Varying this Einstein-Hilbert action correctly gives the term $\nabla^2\Phi$ in the Poisson equation but -- because I have to go second order also in the fluid's part of the action -- I also get some linear term as
$$
\nabla^2\Phi=4\pi G n(x)m\left[1-2\Phi \left(3\chi''^2+(\nabla\chi)^2-1\right)\right]~.
$$
While the first term is correct, the second should not be there. I also get similar problems with the Euler and continuity equations.
What am I doing wrong?
